# moment.locale is causing wrong year

Tags: node.js, momentjs, locale

I've been using moment in my nodejs application since 2 years and it's working fine until yesterday 2022-01-01.
moment started to give wrong year date (in server production and dev enviroment)

This is my code

```
const moment = require('moment'); 
console.log(moment().locale('fr').year(2021).week(48).startOf('week').format());
// ouptut 2020-11-23T00:00:00+01:00
console.log(moment().year(2021).week(48).startOf('week').format());
// output 2021-11-21T00:00:00+01:00
```

Here is my dev enviroment:

```
nodejs v10.23.0
npm 6.14.8
package: "moment": "^2.29.1",
```

Comment: Just tried this on momentjs' homepage and can confirm. File a bug report with them. https://github.com/moment/moment/issues

Comment: In fact, it may already be reported https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5960 but looks like the project isn't being actively maintained - see if you can switch to a maintained project, e.g. [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/I18n)

Comment: I don't think that i can switch to a maintained one :/ since the whole application is based on moment dates (HR and pay...) in both server side and front end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can confirm this looks like a bug. Some quick investigation shows it looks like it is related to how the locale changes what the start of a week is, putting `2021`'s "first week" in `2020` and then rewinding, and I think the bug is reported [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5960).

Basically this means you can't trust this mechanism to get to a time

### Workaround

Use `.add` from a known-good value; e.g.

```js
moment('2021-01-01').locale('fr').add(7 * 48, 'days').startOf('week').format();
// => '2021-11-29T00:00:00+00:00'
```

Notice how this still may be different to other locale week behaviour due to the "start of week" being different, in most of the world the week starts on "Monday" but in some places (e.g. the USA) Sunday is the first day of the week

```js
moment('2021-01-01').add(7 * 48, 'days').startOf('week').format();
// => '2021-11-28T00:00:00+00:00' (USA-style default behaviour)
```

#### Consistency

If you don't want this behaviour to change over locales at all, rather than using the "start of the week" you need to pick the day specifically, i.e. `1 = Monday`

```js
const usa = moment('2021-01-01').add(7 * 48, 'days').day(1).format();
const fr = moment('2021-01-01').locale('fr').add(7 * 48, 'days').day(1).format();
usa === fr; // true, both 29th of November
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for your detailed answer, i was looking if there is a "configuration" mistaked rather than refactoring the code (lazy). But your solution made it easier for me. 
Thank you so much